# Is there a way to have multiple email address from multiple add-on domains under the same $5/mo account?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-account, google-apps-email, google-apps-for-work

I'm looking to move my email accounts from a shared hosting solution to Gmail (Google Apps for Work), and I currently have a primary domain, as well as a few (4) "add on domains" that on my shared hosting I have as "under" my main domain.

These other domains also have a few email addresses each, and I'm wondering if for the $5/mo cost of Google Apps for Work (which is obviously quite a bit more than I'm paying for shared hosting as is) I can have my primary domain as the main user, and then use my add-on domains as extra accounts/addresses under the main one (similar to how I do it in shared hosting).

Basically, will I have to pay $25/mo for the 5 domains I have? I'd prefer not to operate out of a single inbox and have my other domain's support emails come into my primary account, but have them separated (obviously fine if it comes out of the total storage quota).

Answer (score 2):

**YES, OF COURSE!**

As a paid account (Google Apps for Work) you have two options to add extra domains:

1. as ALIAS domains and all your existing accounts will have an automatic alias under the added domain, or...
2. as ADDITIONAL domains on your GApps for Work -Control Panel-, you can assign different email aliases of those added domains to your existing user, or even create users that work exclusively under the new domain.

Note: Adding ADDITIONAL domains is only possible for paid panels (GApps for Work), not for old "legacy" (free) GApps panels. Nevertheless adding ALIAS domains is possible in any type of GApps panel.